# Find all integer solutions to $ x^3 - y^3 = 3(x^2 - y^2) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The objective is to find all solutions to
$$ x^3 - y^3 = 3(x^2 - y^2) $$
where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

So far I've got one pair of solution. Try  $(x, y)=(0,0)$:
$$ 0^3-0^3=3(0^2-0^2) \\
0=0 \qquad \text{equation satisfied}$$

Another try $ (x, y) = (x, x)$ then 
$$ x^3 - x^3 = 3(x^2 -x^2) \\
0 = 0 \qquad \text{equation satisfied}$$

But the above are just particular solutions. To find all $(x, y)$ pairs, I tried:

$$\begin{aligned}
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) &= 3(x+y)(x-y) \\
x^2+xy+y^2 &= 3(x+y) \end{aligned}\\
\begin{aligned}
x^2+xy+y^2-3x-3y &= 0 \\
x^2+x(y-3)+y(y-3) &=0 \\
 x^2 + (y-3)(x+y) &= 0 \end{aligned}$$

What now? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Would be baskara a good way?

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, we can say that whenever $(x,y)$ is a solution, $(y,x)$ is also a solution. Also, one of them must be positive integer, as $x+y=\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{3}>0$

Apply quadratic formula in $3$ specific cases, when $y=1,2,3.$ We get $(2,2), (-1,2), (0,3), (3,0), (2,-1)$ as the integer solutions in these cases. There is no other case, as otherwise $y>3$ or $x>3$ and Left Hand Side of the last equation you wrote will be strictly positive.

Hope it is helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

$x=y$ and $x=3$ with $y=0$ (or $x=0$ with $y=3$) are trivial answers. To show there are no others for $x\ne y$, let $n=x+y$, then the expression can be written $x^2+xy+y^2=(x+y)^2 +(3-n)n$ or $x(n-x)+3n-n^2=0$.  Solve the quadratic for $x$ to get $x=\frac{n+\sqrt{12n-3n^2}}{2}$. Since the discriminant has to be real, $n\le 4$, and a perfect square to get an integer solution.  The only possibilities are $n=1$ giving $(2,-1)$ (not allowed) and $n=3$ giving $(3,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

So first you factorize the expression:
**$$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-3x-3y)=0$$**
**$$(x-y)(x^2+x(y-3)+(y^2-3y))=0$$**
When the product of two expressions are $0$ either of them is $0$
So first factor is $(x-y)=0$ giving the solution pair $x=y$ so for all such pairs the equation will be 0.
Second factor can be treated as a quadratic equation in terms of either $x$ or $y$,
**$$x^2+x(y-3)+(y^2-3y)=0$$**
Where you consider each $y$ as a constant and solve the equation to get:
**$$x=\frac{-(y-3)\pm\sqrt{(y-3)^2-4(y^2-3y)}}{2}$$**
**$$x=\frac{-(y-3)\pm\sqrt{3(9-y^2)}}{2}$$** 
For $x$ to be real the quantity inside the square root should be positive, moreover you need the integer solutions for $x$ and $y$ so the only possibility that remains is if the discriminant becomes a perfect square, So $y=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$  but you also want it to be a perfect square so only $y=\pm3$ which gives:
**$$x = 0,3 $$** 
Final solutions:
All integers for which $x=y$,
$(0,3)$,
$(3,-3)$

You can also solve the equation for $y$, hope this helps .....